# CSS @Print styling

Tags: css, printing

At the moment, my webpages print out with half of the final line of a page cut onto the next page.

[image]

Does anyone have any CSS tricks to stop this happening? Our divs of content tend to be quite long, and are edited by people without html knowledge, so putting html page-breaks in is not an option...

The majority of our users use Chrome, so I'm happy for a solution to only apply for that browser if support is inconsistent... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know where you want the page to break. 
You can add the CSS

```
page-break-after: always;
```

This sets whether a page break should occur AFTER a specified element.

Comment: Ah - I made an edit to my inital question just as you wrote this, to explain that I can't do that unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Scor3keeper nice answer!
Also add proper media query, f.e.:

```
@media print and (color) { 
 body { ... }
 h1, h2, p { ... }
}
```

So in bowser you see one design and on the page other.

Comment: Yep, I know to do that thanks... Any solution to the question though? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need in your CSS is :

```
@media print {
    ul, li {page-break-inside: avoid;}
}
```

The page-break-inside property sets whether a page break is allowed inside a specified element and you cannot use this property on absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: Thanks KAD - I like the idea of that a lot, and hadn't thought of it... Chrome seems to ignore all my page-break: avoids, and suggestions about orphans and widows though, and that's not working for me either... Hopefully it will help someone else in future though!